# Corrupted .gif download file using rust but without rust using curl command it works

Tags: http, curl, rust, network-programming

Hi I tried to download a .gif file using curl command in Linux fedora 36 using 
`curl https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft_gamepedia/images/d/d1/Magma_Block_JE2_BE2.gif/revision/latest?cb=20200915183320 --output magma.gif` 
and **it works**

but then I try to do the same thing in rust with this function and curl library

```rust
pub fn download_file(url: &str, path: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut curl = Easy::new();
    curl.http_content_decoding(true)?;
    curl.get(true)?;
    curl.verbose(true)?;
    curl.connect_timeout(Duration::from_secs(3))?;
    curl.dns_cache_timeout(Duration::from_secs(3))?;
    curl.url(url)?;
    curl.write_function(move |data| {
        if fs::write(&path, data).is_err() {
            eprint!(
                "{}: Failed to write to file -> check permission",
                "error".red().bold()
            );
            process::exit(-1);
        }
        Ok(data.len())
    })?;
    curl.perform()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

and for the parameters I use https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/minecraft_gamepedia/images/d/d1/Magma_Block_JE2_BE2.gif/revision/latest?cb=20200915183320 and magma.gif but **doesn't work** it downloads something but it's size is way lower than what is should be and it's **corrupted** and I can't open it


full source: https://github.com/NiiightmareXD/minecraft_block_downloader 
working file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpClR.gif
corrupted file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/amlj2vrd4thtkb8/magma.gif/file
working verbose: https://www.mediafire.com/file/hsb4k8jmam5bmoh/working_verbose.txt/file 
corrupted verbose: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ouu0h88f2dcgiu9/corrupted_verbose.txt/file 
Thanks for reading

Comment: According to the docs, the callback you pass to `write_function` is called every time data needs to be saved, so my guess is that it's getting called multiple times, and each time `fs::write` completely overwrites the previous data. You can either change the callback to append to a file or consider writing to an in-memory buffer like the second example [here](https://docs.rs/curl/0.4.43/curl/easy/struct.Easy.html#method.write_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that the write function overwrite the previous data to file so it gets corrupted so the new code is this and it works

```rust
pub fn download_file(url: &str, path: String) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut curl = Easy::new();
    curl.url(url)?;
    File::create(&path)?;
    let mut file = File::options().write(true).append(true).open(&path)?;
    curl.write_function(move |data| {
        if let Err(e) = file.write_all(data) {
            eprint!("{}: {}", "error".red().bold(), &e);
            process::exit(-1);
        }
        Ok(data.len())
    })?;
    curl.perform()?;
    Ok(())
}
```